# Using Multiple With and Where Clauses on an Import for the same Node type

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

Is there a way to use multiple where clauses as seen below? Currently it will run and process the first group of *MERGE* clauses after the first *WITH* but the second and third *MERGE* groups after the other *WITH* Clauses do not run. I assume it is because the first *WITH* clauses has a following *WHERE NOT* Clause that filters out what the second and third *WITH* Clauses are requesting?
Anyone know of a way to run this all in one still in one statement? I am running this through Kettle, and for my purpose it must be in a single statement.

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///detail.csv' AS row
MERGE   (gpath:GranPath {circPathInstID:row.CircPathInstID})
    ON CREATE SET
        gpath.circPathHumID = row.CircPathHumID,
        gpath.category = row.Type,
    ON MATCH SET
        gpath.circPathHumID = row.CircPathHumID,
        gpath.category = row.Type,
WITH row, gpath
WHERE NOT gpath.category IN ['ETHERNET','PRI TRUNKS','CUSTOMER SIP TRUNKS','ETHERNET TRANSPORT', 'EPON ETHERNET TRANSPORT']
MERGE   (upath:UnmNonEthPath {name:row.CircPathHumID, status:row.CurrentPending})
MERGE   (upath)-[:DATA_SOURCE {source:"GRANITE"}]->(gpath)
WITH row, gpath
WHERE gpath.category IN ['ETHERNET','PRI TRUNKS','CUSTOMER SIP TRUNKS']
MERGE   (usvc:UnmService {name:row.CircPathHumID, status:row.CurrentPending})
MERGE   (usvc)-[:DATA_SOURCE {source:"GRANITE"}]->(gpath)
WITH row, gpath
WHERE gpath.category IN ['ETHERNET TRANSPORT', 'EPON ETHERNET TRANSPORT']
MERGE   (uxp:UnmTransport {name:row.CircPathHumID, status:row.CurrentPending})
MERGE   (uxp)-[:DATA_SOURCE {source:"GRANITE"}]->(gpath)
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything before the 3rd `WITH` clauses works as expected, then it must be the `WHERE` clause right *after* the 3rd `WITH` clause that is failing.

In fact, since your second `WHERE` clause is this (notice the `NOT`):

```
WHERE NOT gpath.category IN [
  'ETHERNET','PRI TRUNKS','CUSTOMER SIP TRUNKS',
  'ETHERNET TRANSPORT','EPON ETHERNET TRANSPORT']
```

and your 3rd is this:

```
WHERE gpath.category IN [
  'ETHERNET','PRI TRUNKS','CUSTOMER SIP TRUNKS']
```

there is *no way* that the 3rd `WHERE` clause can ever succeed.

If you are trying to *conditionally* perform operations, you should look at the APOC procedures for [Conditional Cypher Execution](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/conditionals/#conditionals-case). In your case, since you have 3 conditions and want to write to the DB, you should consider using [apoc.do.case](https://neo4j.com/docs/labs/apoc/current/cypher-execution/conditionals/#conditionals-case).

For example:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///detail.csv' AS row
MERGE (gpath:GranPath {circPathInstID:row.CircPathInstID})
SET
  gpath.circPathHumID = row.CircPathHumID,
  gpath.category = row.Type
WITH row, gpath
CALL apoc.do.case(
  [
    gpath.category IN ['ETHERNET','PRI TRUNKS','CUSTOMER SIP TRUNKS'],
      'MERGE (usvc:UnmService {name:row.CircPathHumID, status:row.CurrentPending})
       MERGE (usvc)-[:DATA_SOURCE {source:"GRANITE"}]->(gpath)',
    gpath.category IN ['ETHERNET TRANSPORT', 'EPON ETHERNET TRANSPORT'],
      'MERGE (uxp:UnmTransport {name:row.CircPathHumID, status:row.CurrentPending})
       MERGE (uxp)-[:DATA_SOURCE {source:"GRANITE"}]->(gpath)'
  ],
  'MERGE (upath:UnmNonEthPath {name:row.CircPathHumID, status:row.CurrentPending})
   MERGE (upath)-[:DATA_SOURCE {source:"GRANITE"}]->(gpath)',
  {row: row, gpath: gpath})
YIELD value
RETURN gpath
```